# Scheme higher-order function

Tags: scheme, racket

I try to create a procedure that converts a binary number in a list to a string. Sample output: `(binary->string '(1 1 0 1 0 0))` should give `"110100"`.

```
(define reduce
      (lambda (op base x) ;passing by name
        (if (null? x)
            base
            (op (car x) (reduce op base (cdr x))))))
```

And here is my code:

```
(define (binary->string lst)  
   (reduce (number->string lst list->string  )))
```

I know it is wrong but it is the best I came out with so far. Please help me to make it work properly.

Comment: `reduce` takes three arguments, but your implementation of `binary->string` is only giving it one argument.

Answer (score 0):

Before I will show you solution, here is some advice: when you write Racket code, you should check correct number of arguments and their type.

In this case, you know that `reduce` needs `(op base x)`, that are three arguments, but when you use some unknown function, like `number->string`, there is [Racket documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org) and after short search, you fill find [`number->string`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._number-%7E3estring%29%29) entry:

> (number->string z [radix]) → string?
>
> z : number?
>
> radix : (or/c 2 8 10 16) = 10
>
> Returns a string that is the printed form of z (see Printing Numbers) in the base specified by radix. If z is inexact, radix must be 10, otherwise the exn:fail:contract exception is raised.
>
> Examples:
>
> (number->string 3.0)
>
> "3.0"
>
> (number->string 255 8)
>
> "377"

As you can see, you can call this function with one or two arguments, but in both cases, they have to be number. But with this call `(number->string lst list->string  )`, you are passing list and procedure- so I can already tell that your code will end with error. And when you try to call your function in REPL, exactly this happens:

```
> (binary->string '(1 0 0 1))
. . number->string: contract violation
  expected: number?
  given: '(1 0 0 1)
  argument position: 1st
  other arguments...:
```

After you carefully check what did you write, you should be able to predict what will happen, before you even run your code.

Here is solution:

```
(define (binary->string lst)
  (reduce string-append "" (map number->string lst)))
```

You will use [`map`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29) to create string from each number in list, then you join these strings with your `reduce` and [`string-append`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._string-append%29%29).

Comment: Thank you very much. I really apretiate your help.